# saving number of kerbals in ship

Tags: kerbal-space-program

Is there any way to save the number of kerbals along with a ship? I always forget that these get reset and launch with less kerbals than expected only to realize my mistake midlanding somewhere.

Comment: I haven't found a way to do this.  You just have to remember to do this before launch.

Comment: bummer. maybe someday this gets implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no stock way, as of 0.23 to save which or how many Kerbals are assigned to each mission.